# Deploying/Hosting .NET Web API on a Different Server From Where it was Developed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, web-deployment

So I am in the works of developing my first API using .net's tools. I have the API up and running locally no problem at all, but when I try and move it onto the server that is going to be hosted on, It no longer can complete any of the requests.

Whenever I try and deploy the entire project I always get a 404. When I only deploy the files inside the actual project, not including the packages I have downloaded to help my API, I get a response but not the full one that it should be returning since it can't find the packages.

So my question is this, is there a way to deploy all the contents of my API using IIS onto an SQL Server 2012 that is separate from where the application is developed? This may be a stupid question, but I've tried a whole bunch of stuff and nothing has worked. Since I'm brand new to this type of web project any input would be greatly appreciated, Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you deploying it? Are you using the publish feature of Visual Studio?

Comment: I was copying the project folder onto the server, then turning it into a web application in IIS

Comment: Try using the [Publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx) feature and see if you still have the same errors.